# Events firing but bool variable not changing in value

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-invocation, events, logs

Given a contract with an event as follows

```
contract test {
    event LogEvent(
        address a,
        bool result
    );    

    function testInputs(some parameters) public (){

        ....

        //set it to pass the if condition
        bool[2] a = [true,true]; 

        //set it to fail the if condition
        //bool[2] a = [false,true]; 

        if(a[1] && a[2])
            LogEvent(msg.sender,true);
        else
            LogEvent(msg.sender,false);
    }  
}
```

I initially transact and set the parameters so that the `if` condition is satisfied and the event fires `true`.

I then transact again and set the parameters so that the `if` condition does not pass. I expect a new event to be fired setting the value to `false`.

However, the value remains true when I check the log. I believe that each event fired should permanently store the value with the transaction. Is that incorrect?

I also tried testing this the other way around. I started with a transaction that fires the event setting it to `false`. That works. Then I transact again, setting it to `true`. Again, that works. However, if I try transacting with incorrect parameters once more, it does not set back to false when I check the log.

Can someone provide an explanation and how to work around that issue?

Comment: Could you please post the actual condition and the code leading up to it?

Comment: @Henk the condition is as simple as the update I just added to the code.

Comment: @Henk yeah, I change it so that it can pass/not pass the if condition.